# remove SID from URL and redirect it to a directory with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to remove the ?sid=123456 (can be any number)

redirect: http://www.mydomain.com/directory-a/directory-b/directory-c/?sid=123456

to: http://www.mydomain.com/directory-a/directory-b/directory-c/

Comment: Also include what all did you try. That would help others in answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question:

> "redirect: http://www.mydomain.com/directory-a/directory-b/directory-c/?sid=123456"
>
> "to: http://www.mydomain.com/directory-a/directory-b/directory-c/"

This one way to do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} sid=\d+.*
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

In short, what the rule does is removing the query string which is what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sid=[0-9]+&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1 [L,R=301]
```